# mysql fetch assoc VS mysql fetch array

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

Below are two methods commonly used in most php codes for fetch mysql data .

1. `mysql_fetch_array()`
2. `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Now, I have a big database. For fetching data in loops (`while`) what's faster and better ?

I found [this benchmark](http://www.spearheadsoftwares.com/tutorials/php-performance-benchmarking/50-mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array-vs-mysql-fetch-object).

Which is your choice?

Comment: I prefer the ASSOC route, simply because it's easier to read my own code... :P  This isn't really a question as much as a share your opinion, though.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is faster (a little bit) by itself. But, I would also like to reduce the footprint of my program so, I would avoid mysql_fetch_array() with `MYSQL_BOTH` or default option.

Comment: Associative is favoured when upgrading deprecated SQL that is column name centric. It also makes impact analysis with grep-like tools easier.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on how your tables are setup:

`mysql_fetch_array()` essentially returns two arrays one with numeric index, one with associative string index.

So using `mysql_fetch_array()` without specifying `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM`, or by specifying `MYSQL_BOTH` will return two arrays (basically what `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `mysql_fetch_row()` would return) so `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is faster.

If you have your table setup right and query written properly `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is the way to go, code readability wise `$result['username']` is easier to understand than `$result[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

This Is the result of 
 **mysql_fetch_array()**

```
$row['fieldname'] = 'some value';
```

or

```
$row[0] = some value';
```

This Is the result of **mysql_fetch_assoc()** will only return

```
$row['fieldname'] = 'some value';
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer fetch_assoc. It returns an "associative array" (like a python dictionary). This means your array is indexed by string (in my usual case).

The default for fetch_array gives both numbered indices and associative indices.

But I never use the numbered indices, so I like to get it a tiny bit faster with fetch_assoc

Comment: I think it depends what you are trying to read from database.
If you have a sql-statement like this:
"SELECT `id` FROM `table`"
then it shouldn't matter which one you use.
In this case maybe mysql_fetch_row is a little bit faster as mysql_fetch_assoc.
In this special case I prefer using mysql_fetch_row.

Comment: I've tried it and my guesses have been confirmed. With a query like the one in the example, mysql_fetch_row was a little bit faster ~ 0.0002ms in most cases.
As you can see, this speed difference is so extremely small that it makes practically no difference which function you use. In this case it is more a matter of taste, unless you belong to the micro-optimization group, which in my opinion is more effort than benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The "size" of the query results don't matter in this case.

`mysql_fetch_array()` generally produces overhead by returning an associative array *plus* indexed results.

One should decide on the type of query and the desired results on whether to use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

If the overhead is "neglectable" and I'm sure the query succeeds and I know there's only a single result, I occasionally do:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = 123');
list($column1,$column2) = mysql_fetch_array($q);
mysql_free_result($q);
```

For iterative proceedings (like a `while` loop), this just doesn't cut it. When there's no need for "quick-extracting" results (via a `list` operator) and the result has to be further processed in code, I always use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`*.

---

* When forced to actually *use*  the quite out-dated procedural data retrieval functions of PHP. [There are alternatives](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Yeah, it is. On second thought, PDO still has the same options. You could fetch data *twice* (using `PDO::FETCH_ARRAY`) or not (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`). That last part of my answer, actually, was to hint on more "advanced" techniques in PHP to retrieve data (and to [put consistency into the answer, so it won't be deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124309/change-the-way-really-old-questions-are-deleted)...)

Answer (score 2):

The benchark shown in your example uses mysql_fetch_array() without any argument to specify MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_NUM, so it defaults to MYSQL_BOTH... this will rather skew the result as it has to load twice as many array elements as mysql_fetch_assoc(). So I'd suggest it isn't a valid benchmark.

In reality, there should be very little to differentiate between mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC and mysql_fetch_assoc(), and it cerayinly won't be the biggest overhead in your script.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()` would probably be the better choice. There is a slight performance hit (the mysql extension needs to look up the column names, but that should only happen once, no matter how many rows you have), but probably not enough to justify using `mysql_fetch_array()` instead. `mysql_fetch_array()` can be useful if you're only selecting one column though.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on your definition of big. From that benchmark you can see that it is only before you perform upwards of 1,000,000 million fetches that you actually get a measurable difference? Is your database that big? If not, then go with what is easier for you to use (which is probably to fetch an associative array).

Another point to consider, if it is so big that there is a measurable difference then I would be getting a way from using functions like that all together. Consider using MySQLi or even better use PDO!

Answer (score 1):

Well http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php states

> **Note: Performance**
>
> An important thing to note is that using mysql_fetch_assoc() is not significantly slower than using mysql_fetch_row(), while it provides a significant added value.

So the difference shouldn't be something to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

An additional point to keep in mind is that `fetch_assoc()` may not return every column you expect.  If 2 output columns would have the same name, only the last instance of that column will be retrieved by `fetch_assoc()`.  For example, the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders LEFT JOIN line_items ON orders.id = line_items.order_id
```

Assuming both tables have a column called `id`, the resulting associative array would have a key called `id` whose value is set to `line_items.id` and you would not be able to retrieve `orders.id` from the result!

You can circumvent this duplicate column names issue and continue to use `fetch_assoc()` by manually aliasing your `SELECT` columns, giving each column a unique alias:

```
SELECT 
o.id AS order_id, #unique alias
i.id AS line_item_id, #unique alias
o.date,
i.qty,
i.price
FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN line_items i ON i.order_id = o.id
```

Or you can switch to using `fetch_array()`, which will allow you to access either `id` by index instead of by key

Answer (score 1):

**mysql_fetch_array() vs mysql_fetch_assoc()**

mysql_fetch_array(): Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.
[for better documentation click here! to learn more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
mysql_fetch_assoc(): is equivalent to calling mysql_fetch_array() with MYSQL_ASSOC for the optional second parameter. It only returns an associative array.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.