# PHP: Query was empty when searching

Tags: php, mysql

I need a little help for my problem...

Scene: I was trying to search something in my database but the result is "Query was empty" but the one I'm trying to search is already in my database. I'm trying to search the "Atrium Hotel"

Here's my screenshot of my Database:
[image]

Here's my screenshot of my result Page:

[image]

And Lastly here's my code:

```
<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search Building' onClick="this.form.action='search_bldg.php'; this.form.submit()">
<input type="text" id="idSearch"name="searchBldg" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchBldg']; ?>">        
<fieldset  width= "50px">
<legend>BUILDING/S</legend>
<?php
$search = $_POST["searchBldg"];
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%$search%'"); 
$result = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo $row['fldBldgName']; 

} 
?>
</fieldset>
```

I was wondering what is the problem in my query...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Don't use `mysql` - it's deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO`. Also, your code is open to SQL inhection attack. Lastly, your code here is incomplete: nowhere does it emit `Query was empty`.

Comment: Like @MikeW said. Plus, are you sure the table and field name are both correct? Try dumping your query using `var_dump("SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%$search%'")` and see what the result is. Maybe there's just a logical error?

Comment: @UrGuardian4ngel...Here's the result with var_dump "string(61) "SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%Atrium Hotel%'" Query was empty".... and the table and field name are correct.

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima better to provide the sqlfiddle example with your sample data + query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your query twice (Line #7 and #8). That may be the problem. Try something like this:

```
<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search Building' onClick="this.form.action='search_bldg.php'; this.form.submit()">
<input type="text" id="idSearch"name="searchBldg" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchBldg']; ?>">        
<fieldset  width= "50px">
<legend>BUILDING/S</legend>
<?php
$search = $_POST["searchBldg"];
$query= "SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%$search%'"; //Your sql
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); //execute your query
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo $row['fldBldgName']; 

} 
?>
</fieldset>
```

P.S. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` since it is deprecated as of PHP 5.4

Comment: Am I missing something here? Shouldn't it be mysql_fetch_assoc ?

Comment: You can either use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`. `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an "associative array". It could be a better choice. You can read about the difference here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540483/mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mysqli` or `PDO` since `mysql_*` is depreciated.

Try the below code: It's using `mysqli` . It should be working...

```
<?php
$search = $_POST["searchBldg"];

//connecting to db...mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db")
$con=mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname);

//searching...
$query= "SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%$search%'"; 

//execute the query
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die(mysqli_error()); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
{ 
echo $row['fldBldgName']; 

} 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code that I'll demonstrate by commenting your code:

```
<input type='submit' name='search' value='Search Building' action='search_bldg.php'  onClick="this.form.submit();"> <!-- setting action-attribute directly in form-tag, no need to use js for that -->
<input type="text" id="idSearch" name="searchBldg" size="40" value="<?php echo $_POST['searchBldg']; ?>">  <!-- added a space between id="search" and name-attribute -->
<fieldset  width= "50px">
<legend>BUILDING/S</legend>
<?php
$search = $_POST["searchBldg"];
$data = "SELECT * FROM tbldata WHERE fldBldgName LIKE '%$search%'"; //mysql_query is removed, because the actual query is executed below 
$result = mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) //mysql_fetch_array doesn't return associative arrays, therefore it's replaced with mysql_fetch_assoc 
{ 
echo $row['fldBldgName']; 

} 
?>

</fieldset>
```

You should of course sanitize data (so not unwanted data gets inserted into db) and use something else besides mysql_* as stated in previous answers.

Another issue (which is not really a problem) is the name of elements, column-names etc. searchBldg is very similar to searchB1dg and it might be easy to do typing-errors which might be hard to find.