# Getting Column Numbers with Actual Column Names in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT last_name, first_name, DOB, site, COUNT(*) AS Num FROM student "
    . "WHERE site = '{$siteRow['site']}' "
    . "GROUP BY last_name, first_name, DOB having Num > 1";
```

When I run this on a MySQL client, I get the appropriate rows.  `last_name`, `first_name`, `DOB`, `site`, and `Num`

However, when I try to do this (and testing with a `var_dump`) thru `php`, I get those same five col;umns, but before each one, I get `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`, and `4` - each one corresponding with the 5 columns above in the order written.

Here is `php`:

```
$result = $DB->query($query);
$cnt = $DB->count($result);
if ($cnt > 0) {
            while ($row = $DB->fetch_array($result)) { // solved; issue here!
                    if (!in_array(strtolower(trim($row['site'])), $dup_student_sites)) {
                    $records[] = $row;  
                    $dup_student_sites[] = strtolower(trim($row['site']));
                    $dupCount++;
                }

            }
        }


var_dump($records);  // tested here to see result with row numbers
```

Here is the output of the var_dump (partial):

```
array(111) {
  [0] =>
  array(10) {
    [0] =>
    string(7) "---"
    's_s_last_name' =>
    string(7) "---"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "---"
    's_s_first_name' =>
    string(4) "---"
    [2] =>
    string(10) "2003-03-20"
    's_s_DOB' =>
    string(10) "2003-03-20"
    [3] =>
    string(8) "---"
    's_s_site' =>
    string(8) "---"
    [4] =>
    string(1) "2"
    'Num' =>
    string(1) "2"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't give such watered-down answers but:

The likely issue is `$DB->fetch_array`

The likely solution is to change it to `$DB->fetch_assoc`

**Explanation**

Same idea as this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540590/2191572

Comment: As you typed this I realized that was the issue. Marking you correct when time allows.

Comment: Haha I appreciate it. I am going to expand on my answer a bit just for future visitors

Comment: Sure I can go look it up in the manual, but I always get those two confused; so any simple explanation is always appreciated!

Comment: I would recommend going as far as looking for all instances of `fetch_array` in your web-app and switching it to `fetch_assoc` granted that you aren't displaying the results using `$row[0]` and such

Comment: After reading that link you posted I completely get it now and see what happened above. Thanks again.