# MYSQL Select query for displaying data on a table is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display the data loaded from database after it is inserted using the function add_data() but it's not displaying the data on the table.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn_add_details'])) {
add_data();
include("db_PSIS.php");
$sql2="SELECT * FROM sample_barcode WHERE IDRec='".$row['IDRec']."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if(!$result2) {
echo "<h1>Could not process query this time. Please try again later!</h1>";
}
else {
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

echo "<form name='form2' method='POST'>";
echo "<table class='output' border=2 align=center>";
echo "<tr class='thcolor'>";
echo "<th>Parent</th>";
echo "<th>LOT Traveller No.</th>";
echo "<th>Datecode</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['Datecode']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<br><h1>Data successfully loaded!</h1>";
}
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Here's the function for adding data on the database:

```
function add_data() {

include("db_PSIS.php");
$sql="INSERT INTO sample_barcode (LotTraveller, ShipmentLotNumber) VALUES ('".$_POST['traveller']."', '".$_POST['datecode']."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
mysql_close($link);

}
```

Here's the code for database connection:

```
<?php
$username="****";
$password="****";
$database="****";
$hostname="****";
$link=@mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password)
or die ("...cannot connect database, using $username for $hostname");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'"); //指定数据库字符集
mysql_select_db($database,$link);
```

?>

Here's the form input:

```
<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>

<tr>
<th align="right">Parent Traveller: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="traveller" size="20" value="<?php if(empty($_POST['traveller'])) {echo ''; } else { echo $row2['LotTraveller']; } ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Date Code: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="datecode" size="20" value="<?php if(empty($_POST['traveller'])) {echo ''; } else { echo $row2['ShipmentLotNumber']; } ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Traveller 1: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="traveller1" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Date Code: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="datecode1" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Traveller 2: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="traveller2" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right">Date Code: </th>
<td><input type="text" name="datecode2" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align="right"> </th>
<td><input type="hidden" name="id" size="20" value="<?php if(empty($_POST['traveller'])) {echo ''; } else {echo $row2['IDRec'];} ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="btn_add_details" id="btn_add_details" onClick="return check_submit();" value="Add the Detail(s)" onfocus="setStyle(this.id)"
    style="color: #000000;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #7bf #07c #07c #4AA02C;
    background-color: #09f;
    font-family: Georgia, ..., serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;" /> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The loop should only be running on the row - from the **tr** to **/tr**.

Comment: What is it displaying?

Comment: You print a form for every row. As @user2182349 said echo only <tr> content in the while loop. Also where is the code for add_data(); Finally you use the deprecated mysql_* functions and furthermore you are in danger of SQL Injection.

Comment: It only display the message "Data successfully loaded!". but the table not displayed.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis yeah i know about the deprecated mysql, its just i need to use it. Please see above, I add the function for adding data.

Comment: I think that you need: $row['IDRec'] = mysql_insert_id(); before the SELECT query.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis I added that line but still not showing the table.

Comment: Can you show include("db_PSIS.php"); code? If you close $link then maybe you have to make a new connection.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis I added the database connection above

Comment: change $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)  to $row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)

Comment: echo $row['IDRec']; and tell us if it prints anything.

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis it displayed 0

Comment: Where is the value for `$row['IDRec']` coming from? Is it even loading a value?

Comment: Fix that and it should be ok.

Comment: @Kuya It is from the database. The insert query is working. And values are being added on it.

Comment: Is `IDRec` your PK field? Does it auto-increment?

Comment: HERE YOU GO KID http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540483/mysql-fetch-assoc-vs-mysql-fetch-array

Comment: @bassxzero I already used assoc. But still not working

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that `IDRec` is your PK and is set to auto-increment, AND you are pulling records based on a single number... you will never get more than one result in your resultset.

Change this code block...

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM sample_barcode WHERE IDRec='".$row['IDRec']."'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
if(!$result2) {
echo "<h1>Could not process query this time. Please try again later!</h1>";
}
else {
while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2)) { 

echo "<form name='form2' method='POST'>";
echo "<table class='output' border=2 align=center>";
echo "<tr class='thcolor'>";
echo "<th>Parent</th>";
echo "<th>LOT Traveller No.</th>";
echo "<th>Datecode</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['Datecode']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<br><h1>Data successfully loaded!</h1>";
}
mysql_close($link);
}
```

To this...

```
$sql2="SELECT * FROM sample_barcode WHERE IDRec=".$row['IDRec']."";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result2); // added this line
if(!$result2) {
echo "<h1>Could not process query this time. Please try again later!</h1>";
}
else {

echo "<form name='form2' method='POST'>";
echo "<table class='output' border=2 align=center>";
echo "<tr class='thcolor'>";
echo "<th>Parent</th>";
echo "<th>LOT Traveller No.</th>";
echo "<th>Datecode</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['LotTraveller']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row2['Datecode']."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
echo "<br><h1>Data successfully loaded!</h1>";
}
mysql_close($link);
}
```

In the first line I removed the single quotes around your `IDRec` - this is an integer so single quotes are not needed.

Removed your while loop - you will only ever get one result so a loop is not needed.

Also, this doesn't appear to actually be a form so you can also remove your `<form> </form>` tags.

Finally, start learning `pdo_mysql`. my_sql has been deprecated. Anyone still using this code will wake up one day to find out that their website has magically stopped functioning.

**EDIT**

In your add_data function, change it to this...

```
function add_data() {

include("db_PSIS.php");
$sql="INSERT INTO sample_barcode (LotTraveller, ShipmentLotNumber) VALUES ('".$_POST['traveller']."', '".$_POST['datecode']."')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$sql="SELECT * FROM sample_barcode ORDER BY IDRec DESC"; // added this line
$result=mysql_query($sql); // added this line
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // changed this line from array to assoc
mysql_close($link);
}
```

This will get the result of the data you just entered. I added a query to get the data you need to display.

Comment: It shows the message Could not process query this time. Please try again later!. I think there something wrong with IDRec, but I don't what it is.

Comment: In your add_data() function... change `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` to `$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`. Let me know what happens.

Comment: It displayed "Data successfully loaded" and the table without the data. Also I changed $row['IDRec'] into $_POST['id'] in the select query.

Comment: It displayed "Data successfully loaded" and the table without the data. Also I changed $row['IDRec'] into $_POST['id'] in the select query coz I'm trying to put the value of IDRec in the textbox for id.

Comment: Please see above. i added the form inputs.